# What is the formula for diminishing percentages?

Tags: functions, exponential-function

$0.1$ 1 times is $0.1$
i.e.: $x$
$0.1$ 2 times is $−0.1^2+2*0.1 = 0.19$
i.e.: $(1-x)*x+x$
$0.1$ 3 times is $0.1^3-3*0.1^2+3*0.1 = 0.271$
i.e.: $(1-((1-x)*x+x))*x+(1-x)*x+x$
$0.1$ 4 times is $-0.1^4+4*0.1^3-6*0.1^2+4*0.1 = 0.3439$
i.e.: $(1-((1-((1-x)*x+x))*x+(1-x)*x+x))*x+(1-((1-x)*x+x))*x+(1-x)*x+x$

How can I find the function of this where $f(n)$ gives 0.1 $n$ times?
IE: $f(1) = 0.1$ | $f(2) = 0.19$ | $f(3) = 0.271$ | $f(4) = 0.3439$

Further illustrated in words:

1x: You have a 10% chance to do something.
2x: You have a 19% chance to do something.
3x: You have a 27.1% chance to do something.
4x: You have a 34.39% chance to do something.

Comment: Try to look at the remaining total, rather than the decrease. So 0.9 instead of 0.1, 0.81 instead of 0.19, and so on. Percentages work better that way.

Comment: That looks like it would be adding an unnecessary step for what I'm looking for though. Lets say you have a 10% chance to do something. Then you have two 10% chances to do something. It can be either 20% (additive) 21% (multiplicative) or 19% (diminishing) I'm trying to find that 19% chance to do it and not the 81% chance to not do it.

Comment: What does "0.1 2 times" mean, and how do you get the formula $-0.1^2+2\cdot 0.1$ for it?

Comment: 0.1 2 times means $(1−x)∗x+x$ and that formula is it simplified.

Comment: You are looking for the pattern. I'm telling you a different way of looking at your problem where I believe the pattern emerges much easier. It's your choice if you want to disregard that, but I still suggest you take a look at it. I also happen to think it is an easier way to get at the actual number you want, even though it may seem roundabout at first glance.

Comment: @Arthur you're correct. Took me a while to see that I was just doing: $Y=1-(1*0.9^x)$

Answer (score 1):

Credits to @Arthur for the correct information which led to finding the answer. Instead of looking for an Exponential Decay (increasing form) it was much easier to invert an Exponential Decay function. The answer to my inquiry was:

$$Y=1-(0.9^x)$$

This successfully returns what I was searching for. IE:

X = 2
$Y=1-(0.9^2)$
$Y=1-(0.81)$
$Y=0.19$

X = 4
$Y=1-(0.9^4)$
$Y=1-(0.6561)$
$Y=0.3439$

Comment: Note that the formulas you have in your question post is the result of taking $1-(1-0.1)^x$, and expanding the bracket. For instance, $x = 3$ gives $$1-(1-0.1)^3 \\= 1-(1^3 - 3\cdot 1^2\cdot 0.1 + 3\cdot 1\cdot 0.1^2 - 0.1^3) \\=3\cdot 0.1 - 3\cdot 0.1^2 + 0.1^3$$Your (-1, 2), (1, -3, 3), (-1, 4, -6, 4) pattern is a hint that something like this is taking place, but it can be a little difficult to piece together because the two 1's have cancelled away, making the pattern incomplete.